# ESP32 GPIO pin Interrupts configured as RISING are repeating on HIGH

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I am developing a data logger with an ESP32 nodemcu-32s dev board using VSCode and PlatformIO, with Arduino Core.

All is going well with exception that the GPIO I'm using to trigger an interrupt on a RISING input pulse generates a continuous stream of repeat interrupts when the input stays HIGH. When it goes LOW, the interrupts cease. Here is the code that configures the GPIO:

```
pinMode(OutputPin1, OUTPUT);  //Set Digital I/O status for OutputPin1
digitalWrite(OutputPin1, HIGH);  //default output pin #1 set to 'HIGH'
pinMode(interruptPin1, INPUT);    // Set Digital I/O status for interruptPin1
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin1), ISR1, RISING);  //Set pin 'interruptPin1' to trigger interrupt on rising edge and run 'ISR1' ISR function
```

OutputPin1 is used to provide HIGH voltage through a momentary button switch configured in the usual way.  When the button is released, a resistor pulls the signal LOW.  So the simple goal is to trigger one interrupt per button press.

What happens instead is I get a repeating series of interrupts as long as I hold the INPUT HIGH by pressing the button.  When I release the button, allowing it to pull down to LOW again, the stream of interrupts stops.  I've confirmed the input levels on a scope.

I am pretty new to ESP32 and slow to find the right documentation, but I have experimented with all the interrupt modes - RISING, FALLING, HIGH, LOW, CHANGE.  This behavior is constant regardless of what mode I select in attachInterruupt().  For example, even if I specify LOW trigger, the interrupts continue to occur on HIGH (when I press and hold the button).  When I release the button, the interrupts stop.  So it kind of acts like the mode is HIGH, with repeating interrupts.

The code I'm using (mapped to the specific GPIOs on that MCU) works properly on Arduino MKR1010, so something is obviously different with the ESP32 specifically.  I have looked through libraries and tried using the Espressif IDF #defines (e.g. GPIO_INTR_POSEDGE) , but they aren't making any difference in the behavior.

I haven't found the header files for ESP32 GPIO defines yet, but in VSCode I can see from hovering over the code the following:

```
 RISING = 0x01
 FALLING = 0x02
 LOW = 0x0
 HIGH = 0x1
 CHANGE = 0x2
```

Question 1: Can anyone give me a clue why this might happen?
Question 2: Is there a definition in ESP32 / Arduino to trigger repeating interrupts on a GPIO input level?  I didn't know this was a thing.

Thanks

Comment: bouncing of the switch?

Answer (score 0):

A common procedure is to disable interrupt in your ISR and reenable it once you are out of ISR.  I hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).